# Current navigation highlight for a menu that may be modified by the user?

Tags: navigation

I'm using the following to list my pages:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
</ul>
```

is there a way of highlight the link of the page of the current in the navigation.
It shouldn't be fixed. The user should be able to call the page whatever he or she wants, and create as much pages as he or she wants (the highlight feature should still work).

Any suggestions or tutorials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wp_list_pages has support for CSS styles. 
The current page is marked with the class .current_page_item. You can style it as you want.

Check http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#Markup_and_styling_of_page_items
for reference.

Answer (score -1):

You can also have more control using the wp_nav_menu function for WordPress, here's the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) for that. I also wrote a post outlining how to style the current page item while using the wp_nav_menu [here](http://wp.me/p2qnNl-t).